# What is the easiest way to find all the settings in your .vimrc/init.vim that are already default?

Tags: vim, neovim

In neovim (and sometimes even in vim) some [default settings change](https://neovim.io/doc/user/vim_diff.html#nvim-defaults) occasionally. I'd like to keep my `.vimrc` and `init.vim` tidy and remove the settings which are already the default. Is there an easy way to find those superfluous options?

An example, in neovim they recently enabled `hidden` by default, so I can remove it now from `init.vim`. But there's more options and they are changing over time too, so keeping track of them manually is cumbersome and error prone. I'm looking for a command or so that lists all the options which are not needed anymore.

Comment: IMO, it's a good idea to keep those settings in your file. because it works no matter how they change the options, particularly, during the development of nvim.

Comment: Changing the default settings in neovim seems to be the result of a rather lengthy process, for vim it is less likely for a default setting to change because they value backwards compatibility over everything. So I'm willing to take the risk here for the benefit of a tidy configuration file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The command `:set` without parameters displays all settings that *are changed*.

Put them into buffer (e.g. `"=execute("set!")<CR>p`) and compare with your vimrc.

In neovim you have to use `"=execute("set")<CR>p` (i.e. without exclamation mark) instead.

Comment: The above command doesn't seem to work, can you check if it is correct?

Comment: @BastianVenthur This is in Normal mode.